# I need to turn on the activity Camera model that could switch between video and photo

Tags: android, android-camera, android-videoview

Hi I need to turn on the activity Camera model that could switch between video and photo.

If you use

```
Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
```

or

```
Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent (MediaStore.ACTION_VIDEO_CAPTURE);
```

Can I take pictures and feeds or returns to one outcome. This is ok but I need to be able to switch between camera and video.

and if you use that does not return results

```
Intent takeVideoIntent = new Intent(MediaStore.INTENT_ACTION_STILL_IMAGE_CAMERA);
```

Do you have any simple solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I need to turn on the activity Camera model that could switch between video and photo.

There is no requirement that any camera app that you start with those `Intent` structures support *both* still images and video, let alone allow the user to switch between them on the fly.

You will need to either give the user different triggers to launch their chosen camera app in the appropriate mode (video, photo), or write your own camera code using `Camera` and `MediaRecorder`.